# CUDA default streams and CUDA_API_PER_THREAD_DEFAULT_STREAM

Tags: c++, cuda

[The documentation here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/stream-sync-behavior.html) tries to explain how default streams are handled.

Given code like this (ignoring allocation errors):

```
char *ptr;
char source[1000000];
cudaMalloc((void**)&ptr, 1000000);
cudaMemcpyAsync(ptr, source, 1000000, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
myKernel<<<1000, 1000>>>(ptr);
```

Is there a risk that `myKernel` will start before `cudaMemcpyAsync` finishes copying? I think "No" because this is a "Legacy default stream" as described in the documentation.

However, if I compile with `CUDA_API_PER_THREAD_DEFAULT_STREAM` what happens? The text for "Per-thread default stream" says:

> The per-thread default stream is an implicit stream local to both the thread and the `CUcontext`, and which does not synchronize with other streams (just like explcitly created streams). The per-thread default stream is not a non-blocking stream and will synchronize with the legacy default stream if both are used in a program.

I think this might also be OK as both `cudaMemcpyAsync` and `myKernel` are effectively using `CU_STREAM_PER_THREAD`; am I correct?

---

<sub>The reason I ask is that I have a really weird intermittent CUDA error 77 in a kernel that I can only explain by a `cudaMemcpyAsync` not finishing before calling `myKernel`, which would mean that I am not understanding the documentation. The real code is too involved and too proprietary to make an MCVE, though.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a risk that myKernel will start before cudaMemcpyAsync
>   finishes copying? I think "No" because this is a "Legacy default
>   stream" as described in the documentation.

No that can't happen because, as you note, the legacy default stream (stream 0) is blocking under all circumstances.

> However, if I compile with CUDA_API_PER_THREAD_DEFAULT_STREAM what happens?

Almost nothing changes. The per-thread default stream isn't blocking, so other streams and other threads using their default streams could operate concurrently within the context. Both operations are, however, still in the same stream and are sequential with respect to one another. The only way overlap could occur between the two operations would be if `source` was a non-pageable memory allocation which permitted overlap between the transfer and the kernel execution. Otherwise, they will run sequentially because of the ordering property of the stream and the restrictions imposed by the host source memory.

If you are having a real problem with suspected unexpected overlap of operations, you should be able to confirm this by profiling.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; I have also added `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` between the calls and am effectively running single-threaded, so the bug must be elsewhere and my new suspect is that I have a `cudaSetDevice()` timing issue, as I have two GPUs in my computer.